# Filter an array where the values in the first array contain the values in the second array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

In typescript I have two arrays:

```
var StarWarsChars: any = [
      "Jedi Yoda",
      "Jedi Mace Windu",
      "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn",
      "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn",
      "Jedi Obi-Wan Kenobi",
      "Sith Count Dooku",
      "Sith Darth Sidious",
      "Droid R2-D2",
      "Droid R2-D2",
      "Droid C-3PO",
      "Droid BB-8"
    ];

var StarWarsFilter: any = ["Jedi", "Sith"];
```

and I wish to create a third array consisting of values from the StarWarsChars array where the values contain the values in the StarWarsFilter. I know how to filter on a single value:

```
var StarWarsFiltered = StarWarsChars.filter(e =>
      e.includes(StarWarsFilter[0])
    );
```

which returns:

```
0: "Jedi Yoda"
1: "Jedi Mace Windu"
2: "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn"
3: "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn"
4: "Jedi Obi-Wan Kenobi"
```

but I don't know how to perform this filter on all values in StarWarsFilter. I could try a loop but I imagine there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would suggest using the correct types for your arrays: `string[]`

You should be able to do the following:

```
var StarWarsChars: string[] = [
  "Jedi Yoda",
  "Jedi Mace Windu",
  "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn",
  "Jedi Qui-Gon Jinn",
  "Jedi Obi-Wan Kenobi",
  "Sith Count Dooku",
  "Sith Darth Sidious",
  "Droid R2-D2",
  "Droid R2-D2",
  "Droid C-3PO",
  "Droid BB-8"
];

var StarWarsFilter: string[] = ["Jedi", "Sith"];

var StarWarsFiltered = StarWarsChars.filter(e =>
      StarWarsFilter.some(f => e.includes(f))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const StarWarsFiltered = 
   StarWarsChars.filter(x => x.split(' ').some(y => StarWarsFilter.includes(y)));`

This will return all the items in StarWarsChars that contain a word in StarWarsFilter